# Computing inverses in a binary field

Tags: finite-field

Please suggest how can i solve the below question

What is the inverse of {03} in GF (2^8) with the irreducible polynomial x8+x4+x3+x+1?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please describe what are the difficulties you are encountering?

Anyway, the polynomial mentioned is the one used for the AES cipher and I suggest you to read [this specification](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) (especially the section 4 which explains briefly the mathematical background).